# Is possible generate git log each time I push code

Tags: json, git

I found out code online can generate a git log JSON file, but it's extremely long, and I don't think it's practical to ask each dev to run this before they push code to github. So I wonder, is there any way I can combine this when I do `git push` in a shorter version?

Here's git log JSON code I found:

```
git log --pretty=format:'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n  "abbreviated_commit": "%h",%n  "tree": "%T",%n  "abbreviated_tree": "%t",%n  "parent": "%P",%n  "abbreviated_parent": "%p",%n  "refs": "%D",%n  "encoding": "%e",%n  "subject": "%s",%n  "sanitized_subject_line": "%f",%n  "body": "%b",%n  "commit_notes": "%N",%n  "verification_flag": "%G?",%n  "signer": "%GS",%n  "signer_key": "%GK",%n  "author": {%n    "name": "%aN",%n    "email": "%aE",%n    "date": "%aD"%n  },%n  "commiter": {%n    "name": "%cN",%n    "email": "%cE",%n    "date": "%cD"%n  }%n},' > gitLog.json
```

[Found this from here](https://gist.github.com/varemenos/e95c2e098e657c7688fd)

I have npm package.json and wonder, can I add a special command in the `scripts:{}` sections? But that still require running two commands to generate that JSON file.

Trying to make this work for our users who do not have access for our private repository, but can see what we have been working on.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can setup a pre push script using the Husky npm package

Answer (score 1):

Use [git hooks](https://githooks.com). Set up a [post-commit hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L147) with the command from your question and each time a new commit is made, the `gitLog.json` will be updated.